# React Native Redux useSelector() not updating component when state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having a weird bug with Redux.

I'm running a React Native with Expo project, and I've been using Redux for two years now on this app.

I made some major changes to our APIs and updated Redux, but it seems like this one specific component does not read the Redux state properly, but the same exact logic in another component works perfectly.

I have function **handleUpdateRecentResource** that gets called when the user presses the button, in that function I check the Redux state **recentResources** for the info that exists there, and then logic to see if it exists to update, if it reached the set limit of 10 etc.

Issue: On the problematic component when it reads the **recentResources** it does not get an updated version, so let's say I just pressed the button, it created an object, it updates Redux, (Slice bellow) and My database through the APIs, then I have the console log for the state, it shows the updated Redux state, but when I click again and call the function again, it does not reflect the **recentResources** properly. But on the other component (Healthy Component below) it has the same logic and works perfectly fine.

What is happening here?

**Problematic Component**

```
const LibraryScreen = () => {
  const [viewTitle, setViewTitle] = useState("false");
  const [text, setText] = useState("View with Titles");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  // ============ Hooks =========================
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // ============ Selectors ======================
  const { recentResources } = useSelector((state) => state.books);
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const changeView = () => {
    if (viewTitle === "false") {
      setViewTitle("true");
      setText("View with Images");
    } else {
      setViewTitle("false");
      setText("View with Titles");
    }
  };

  console.log(recentResources);

  const handleUpdateRecentResource = async (sku, cover_uri, title) => {
    console.log("Recent Resources", recentResources);

    // See if resource already exists in the recent recourses array
    const existingRecentResource = recentResources.find((recentResource) => {
      return recentResource.sku === sku;
    });

    if (existingRecentResource) {
      // Resource already exists
      // Update recent Resource && save to Redux
      await updateRecentResourceApi(
        existingRecentResource.id,
        existingRecentResource.title
      ).then((res) => {
        // console.log("updateSelectedRecentResource", res);
        dispatch(updateSelectedRecentResource(res));
      });
    } else {
      // Book does not exist
      // Check if recent resources array is at 10 capacity
      if (recentResources.length >= 10) {
        // book already has 10 in there
        // Delete last item from the array from AWS
        await deleteRecentBookApi(
          recentResources[recentResources.length - 1].id
        );
        // Create new recent resource in AWS || Delete last item and unshift new on in redux
        await createRecentResourcesApi({
          sku: sku,
          title: title,
          cover_uri: cover_uri,
          userId: user.userId,
        }).then((res) => {
          // console.log("deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResources", res);
          // dispatch(deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResource(res));
        });
      } else {
        // Array is NOT at 10 capacity
        // Create new recent resource and add to redux array
        await createRecentResourcesApi({
          sku: sku,
          title: title,
          cover_uri: cover_uri,
          userId: user.userId,
        }).then((res) => {
          dispatch(addNewSelectedRecentResource(res));
          // console.log("deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResources", res);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View className="bg-white h-full" stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}>
      <View className="p-5 pt-0 h-full">
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <TouchableOpacity className="pt-3" onPress={changeView}>
            <Text style={[styles.textColor]}>{text}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {viewTitle === "false" ? (
          <Books handleUpdateRecentResource={handleUpdateRecentResource} />
        ) : (
          <BooksTitleList tab="resources" />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
export default LibraryScreen;
```

**Healthy Component with the same logic**

```
const RecentResources = ({ tab }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  // ============ Hooks =========================
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // ============ Selectors ======================
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { recentResources } = useSelector((state) => state.books);

  const placeholderImage =
    "https://cdn-d8.nypl.org/s3fs-public/blogs/sJ3CT4V.gif";

  const handleUpdateRecentResource = async (sku, cover_uri, title) => {
    console.log("Recent Resources", recentResources);

    // See if resource already exists in the recent recourses array
    const existingRecentResource = recentResources.find((recentResource) => {
      return recentResource.sku === sku;
    });

    if (existingRecentResource) {
      // Resource already exists
      // Update recent Resource && save to Redux
      await updateRecentResourceApi(
        existingRecentResource.id,
        existingRecentResource.title
      ).then((res) => {
        // console.log("updateSelectedRecentResource", res);
        dispatch(updateSelectedRecentResource(res));
      });
    } else {
      // Book does not exist
      // Check if recent resources array is at 10 capacity
      if (recentResources.length >= 10) {
        // book already has 10 in there
        // Delete last item from the array from AWS
        await deleteRecentBookApi(
          recentResources[recentResources.length - 1].id
        );
        // Create new recent resource in AWS || Delete last item and unshift new on in redux
        await createRecentResourcesApi({
          sku: sku,
          title: title,
          cover_uri: cover_uri,
          userId: user.userId,
        }).then((res) => {
          // console.log("deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResources", res);
          // dispatch(deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResource(res));
        });
      } else {
        // Array is NOT at 10 capacity
        // Create new recent resource and add to redux array
        await createRecentResourcesApi({
          sku: sku,
          title: title,
          cover_uri: cover_uri,
          userId: user.userId,
        }).then((res) => {
          dispatch(addNewSelectedRecentResource(res));
          // console.log("deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResources", res);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlashList
        // data={tab === "resources" ? recentRources : bookList}
        data={recentResources}
        horizontal
        estimatedItemSize={20}
        initialNumToRender={3}
        forceNonDeterministicRendering
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={tw`ml-1`}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 219,
                height: 270,
                resizeMode: "contain",
              }}
              source={{
                // uri: item.cover_uri,
                uri:
                  item.cover_uri ===
                  "https://www.blue360media.com/media/catalog/productno_selection"
                    ? placeholderImage
                    : item.cover_uri,
              }}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styles.button, tw`rounded-md mt-5 ml-14`]}
              onPress={() => {
                handleUpdateRecentResource(
                  item.sku,
                  item.cover_uri,
                  item.title
                );

                dispatch(setTitle(item.title));
                dispatch(setSku(item.sku));

                dispatch(setCoverUri(item.cover_uri));

                navigation.navigate("Book Screen");
              }}
            >
              <Text style={tw`text-white text-center `}>Read</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default RecentResources;
```

**Redux Slice**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  books: [],
  recentResources: [],
};

export const booksSlice = createSlice({
  name: "books",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setBooks: (state, action) => {
      state.books = action.payload;
    },
    setRecentResources: (state, action) => {
      state.recentResources = action.payload;
    },
    updateSelectedRecentResource: (state, action) => {
      // find index of resource
      const index = state.recentResources.findIndex(
        (recentResource) => recentResource.id === action.payload.id
      );
      // create a copy
      const updatedSelectedRecentResources = [...state.recentResources];
      // fail safe, we know it exists...
      if (index !== -1) {
        // remove object from old position
        updatedSelectedRecentResources.splice(index, 1);
        // add the updated to 0 index
        updatedSelectedRecentResources.unshift(action.payload);
        state.recentResources = updatedSelectedRecentResources;
      }
    },
    deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResource: (state, action) => {
      state.recentResources.pop();
      state.recentResources.unshift(action.payload);
    },
    addNewSelectedRecentResource: (state, action) => {
      state.recentResources.unshift(action.payload);
    },
    clearRecentResources: (state, action) => {
      state.recentResources = [];
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setBooks,
  setRecentResources,
  updateSelectedRecentResource,
  deleteAndCreateSelectedRecentResource,
  addNewSelectedRecentResource,
  clearRecentResources,
} = booksSlice.actions;

export default booksSlice.reducer;
```

**Book Component**

```
const Books = ({ handleUpdateRecentResource }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [recentResourcesArray, setRecentResourcesArray] = useState([]);
  //  ============ Hooks ==================

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // ============= Selectors ===================
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { recentResources, books } = useSelector((state) => state.books);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setRecentResourcesArray(recentResources);
  // }, [recentResources]);

  const placeholderImage =
    "https://cdn-d8.nypl.org/s3fs-public/blogs/sJ3CT4V.gif";

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlashList
        data={books}
        horizontal
        estimatedItemSize={20}
        initialNumToRender={3}
        forceNonDeterministicRendering
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={tw`ml-1`}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 219,
                height: 270,
                resizeMode: "contain",
              }}
              source={{
                // uri: item.cover_uri,
                uri:
                  item.cover_uri ===
                  "https://www.blue360media.com/media/catalog/productno_selection"
                    ? placeholderImage
                    : item.cover_uri,
              }}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styles.button, tw`rounded-md mt-5 ml-14`]}
              onPress={() => {
          
                handleUpdateRecentResource(
                  item.sku,
                  item.cover_uri,
                  item.title
                );
                dispatch(setTitle(item.title));
                dispatch(setSku(item.sku));

                dispatch(setCoverUri(item.cover_uri));

                // navigation.navigate("Book Screen");
              }}
            >
              <Text style={tw`text-white text-center `}>Read12345</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default Books;
```

Comment: Can you provide   `Books` component code, more especially, usage of   handleUpdateRecentResource props ?

Comment: yeah absolutely, I've edited my post to include the book component. 
It is just an onPress that passes in the info as you can see in the params of the function.

Comment: Yes, as you said, it seems like exactly same logic, only except you are passing handleUpdateRecentResource as props to Books, but for the Healthy component, defined it inside of component.
My preferred suggestion is you can wrap the function with useCallback which you are trying to pass as props, and add required dependencies to useCallback dependency array. It's known as best practices when passing functions as props to child component.

Comment: Yeah the callback is a good idea... But I had the function inside the Books component and not passing it as a prop, and was doing the same exact behavior, I moved it outside to the parent component to see if it would do anything different. I don't understand why on the component I get the updated redux state, but when clicking on the function the function it self does not.